# IIS alwaysAllowedUrls not recognized

Tags: asp.net, iis, requestfiltering

I wanted to add some IIS requestFiltering rules to my web application. I followed folling guides:

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/alwaysallowedurls
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/denyurlsequences

For example, I want to deny Url *test* but enable *testallowed*

So I made following configuration in my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <denyUrlSequences>
        <add sequence="test" />
      </denyUrlSequences>
      <alwaysAllowedUrls>
        <add url="testallowed" />
      </alwaysAllowedUrls>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Wenn calling *mypage/test*, I get the IIS HTTP Error 404.5 Page, which is correct. But I get the same page when calling *mypage/testallowed*. And in my web.config, the Tag alwaysAllowedUrls is underlined and it says:

*The element 'requestFiltering' has invalid child element 'alwaysAllowedUrls'. List of possible elements expected: 'fileExtensions, requestLimits, verbs, hiddenSegments, denyUrlSequences'.*

Comment: Nothing looks wrong with the rules.For the web.config part you verify it in the IIS Schema here C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\schema\IIS_schema.xml . If you do not see it there try reinstalling Request Filtering

Answer (score -1):

this is the syntax as per the IIS documentation :

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <denyUrlSequences>
            <add sequence="bad" />
            <add sequence="sequence" />
         </denyUrlSequences>
         <alwaysAllowedUrls>
            <add url="/bad_sequence.txt" />
         </alwaysAllowedUrls>
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/alwaysallowedurls?showTreeNavigation=true

Comment: This does not answer the question, plus the code is nearly the same as in the question plus your link is already in the question.

Comment: There is a difference though. Notice the URL attribute value. It has a leading '/' , that' very important in order to accept the value as a valid URL.

Comment: Another important thing is, alwaysAllowedUrls is shipped as an enhancement to IIS 7.0, it's not a core feature of IIS 7. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/957508. However if you are on IIS 7.5, it's a core feature.